# Variable oxidation state of transition metal ions

Tags: electrochemistry, ions, stability, transition-metals, oxidation-state

Transition metals can form stable ions with different oxidation states. But I am confused why doesn't only the most stable state exist. Let me clarify my question more:

$$\ce{Ti^{2+} -> Ti^{3+} + e^-} $$
With $E^0 = +0.5~\mathrm{V}$.

This just shows that $\ce{Ti^{3+}}$ is more stable. So my question is that why doesn't $\ce{Ti^{3+}}$ only exist in its most stable form?

Comment: Understanding Latimer, Pourbaix and Frost diagrams might help you understand the relative interconversion of different oxidation states. [here](http://classes.uleth.ca/200501/chem2810a/lecture_20.pdf) and [here](http://www.wou.edu/las/physci/ch462/redox.htm) is a good link. I will post an answer if you still want any clarifications.

Comment: if you look at the electron configurations of the Titanium cations you can see what is stable (titanium 4+ is most stable because it has the same electron configuration as Argon) and Ti(3+) has a half filled 4s-orbital and is relatively stable...

Answer (score 3):

Thermodynamics proposes, kinetics disposes.  The most stable form can have a high activation energy barrier surrounding it.  The medium matters.  Hard Lewis bases (water) stabilize high oxidation states (Cu(II), tungstate).  Soft Lewis bases (acetonitrile) stabilize low oxidation states (Cu(II); $\ce{W(CO)6}$ and http://www.google.com/patents/EP1995347A1?cl=en).

$\ce{Ti^{+4}}$ is the basement, especially with oxygen.  Now rationlalize titanium suboxide Magnéli phases.  They are spectacular as inert electrodes under extreme conditions, re Ebonex.

DOI:10.1016/j.electacta.2010.05.011 
http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/cgi/request_doc?eprintid=152857&_action_null=Request+a+copy